# How to cache BLOB type in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, caching

#### Hi everyone,

**Is there a way to *cache* `BLOB` types temporarily in *Laravel* ?**

Scenario:
I'm gonna cache some data `MEDIUMBLOB` with the size of 2048KB temporarily.
These data are actually parts of a large single file 16MB.
After caching all parts, they will be combined together into a single file, then will be removed from cache.

The content of each single part is given by `file_get_contents` function.

I'm already doing this with `MySQL`. (However, there are lots of queries and takes time to be done.)

Is there a better way to store `MEDIUMBLOB` data temporarily in Cache storage ?

I've faced with `Redis` and `Cache` in Laravel, but I'm not sure they support `MEDIUMBLOB`.

Comment: Yes redis supports this use case however your problem sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) could be useful to provide some more context because I suspect there's better ways to do what you need

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for answering. So can I trust Redis to handle these data ? What is the data type in Redis to store data in ?

Comment: This would be a simple key-value pair basically `Cache::put('key', $data);` also any cache driver should work not just redis. You can then call `Cache::forget('key')` when you want to delete the data (or set an expiry as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#storing-items-in-the-cache) to not worry about deleting items)

Comment: @apokryfos You saved me! As I understood, it's not important what the data type is. `file_get_contents` functions gets the contents as string, right ? That's the point. Thanks a lot for helping me. I'm not sure If this question is useful or not (if not, I would delete it!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the main point. In the end a BLOB is just a string of bytes. The major difference with a formal string type is that a BLOB doesn't have any sort of encoding or collation associated with it. It's a kind of binary string which is another way of saying "generic data". `file_get_contents` also generally returns this sort of "generic data".

Laravel's cache is build to be generic like that so it doesn't have any specific data type associated with it. It's just a store of key/value pairs and the keys must be ascii strings while the values can be anything Laravel serialises things before they go in the cache so basically anything that can be represented as a variable in PHP and is serializable can be cached.

Comment: Well explained. It is possible to deal with `Binary data` as a simple `string`.